# Netbeans CUnit runs once per application launch

Tags: netbeans, cunit

I am using Netbeans 8.1 with CUnit testing. I can run and test my project just fine, and it spits out the correct results. However, when I try to test it again it does not give me results. Instead it only says:

> ```
>  CUnit - A unit testing framework for C - Version 2.1-3
>  http://cunit.sourceforge.net/
> ```

This persists even if I change the actual code of the project. It will only give me the results when I restart the program. I would like to know how to get the updated test results without having to restart the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround: add a dummy C Simple Test test that always passes.

Turned out if I have C Unit and C Simple Test tests in the same project and when I run Test Project from the menu both works properly.